# How to call activity Android from button HTML?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I want to ask how to call activity on Android Studio from my buttom HTML.

This my button html code:

```html
<button id="button" class="buttonHome" style="background:url(assets/scan.png)"></button>
```

and this is my `java.activity`:

```java
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.architectView.onPostCreate();
    try {

 this.architectView.load("file:///android_asset/cobarealobjek/index.html");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this my `.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.geowikitudes.RealObjectActivity">
    <com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView
        android:id="@+id/architectView_real"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

If using a WebView instead of ArchitectView is an option for you, you may want to try using a `JavascriptInterface`.

You would have to define a class for your interface, which you would then bind to your WebViewClient, for example, `AppInterface`.

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    public AppInterface(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // This is where you define the methods you want to be able to call from your web app
    // You have to annotate such methods with @JavascriptInterface
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void startMyActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(mContext, SecondActivity.class);  // Assuming SecondActivity is the name of activity you want to open
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In your main activity file, you could have something like this:

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

Webview webView;
WebViewClient webVC;
// ...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  // Assuming you have a webview with the id of "webview" defined in your layout
    webVC = WebViewClient();

    webView.setWebViewClient(webVC);
    webView.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AppInterface(this), "Android");  // You can set the second parameter to any other string, just make sure that you change it accordingly in your javascript
    webView.loadUrl("yourURL");
    // ...

}
```

Finally, in your HTML/javascript code, you need to call the function via the provided javascript interface:
`<button id="button" class="buttonHome" style="background:url(assets/scan.png)" onclick="Android.startMyActivity();"></button>`

I hope this helps.

Comment: it didn't work., only show white screen. it possible to combine ArchitectView and WebView?

Comment: You may need to declare the internet permission in the android manifest by adding the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> tag, as android might be preventing your WebView from loading webpages.